# What is the font used in the Western Union logo?

Tags: font-identification

My question is really brief.

What is the font used in the Western Union logo?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The font is [Univers 85 Extra Black](http://www.linotype.com/47786/85%20extra%20black-product.html):

[image: Image of Univers 85 Extra Black]

Answer (score 3):

Yuo can use [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to find what the font used. If the font is not recognized you can:

1. [Align letters](http://www.flickr.com/photos/z2054/9109121373/) with Photoshop
2. Go back to WhatTheFont and upload four file

This should give you better results. [See this example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/z2054/9111426552/).

Comment: @Kurt and Zantar I added the instructions in your comments to your answer. If you need to change anything you just have to click the 'Edit' button below it :)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the [Zurich Extra Black](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/zurich/extra-black/) font, If you see look close, the "**T**" character matches exactly with is font.

[image]